# Having a Main datatable class

Tags: asp.net, datatable

I am trying to create a Data Table which i can use with all aspx.cs in my web application instead of my current method of creating a new table on page loadf for each page.

Is there any way i can do this. I have come up with a concept of having a MakeTable.cs class which will create a table then all the aspx.cs files call this class and adds the row of data into this table and saves it.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the datatable on the master page and store in session